# Fish eye menu with jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, fisheye

I want to make a simple fish eye menu for my website like on http://www.smartmeup.org (on left side)

Do you know a jquery plugins or a simple code to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: smartmeup.org: This webpage is not available

Comment: OT: that's one of the most awful menus to use I've ever witnessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some, make your pick:

- [Interface Elements fisheye menu](http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/fisheye)
- [Fisheye js menu by Mark Grabanski](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/fisheye-javascript-menu)
- [Fisheye menu at AjaxDaddy](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-interface-fisheye.html)
- [n.design studio's fisheye menu](http://ndesign-studio.com/blog/css-dock-menu)
- [jqDock by Wizuud](http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jqdock?  It is a jquery plugin

http://www.wizzud.com/jqdock/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some using jquery

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-interface-fisheye.html

http://www.webappers.com/2009/06/02/jqdock-jquery-fish-eye-menu/

http://blog.jquery.com/2007/05/09/fisheye-dock-menu/

http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/fisheyemenu.php

Answer (score 0):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-os-x-style-dock-and-stack-navigation/

I'm posting this because none of the threads ever seem to offer a full solution. great suggestions, but nothing definitive so I thought that I'd put this out there. Hope this helps!!